# I am trying to implement a reset button for my MVC web page, which will clear the data of text boxes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, button, reset

I am implementing reset button and it will clear the data of the text boxes, It is not working properly. Attaching code for reference.

```
      <input type="submit" class="reset" value="Reset" onclick="reset()" />


    function reset() {
    $("#BillRate").val(0);
    $("#PayRate").val(0);
    $("#Markup").val(0);
    $("GrossProfitMargin").val(0);

        jQuery("text-box").val(function () {

            this.BillRate.val = 0;
            this.PayRate = 0;
            this.Markup = 0;
            this.GrossProfitMargin = 0;
        });
    };
```

and my layout looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Calculate", "Calculators", FormMethod.Post))
{

    <table class="table">


        <tr></tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BillRate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.BillRate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.GrossProfitMargin)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.GrossProfitMargin, new { @id = "gpm" })

                <p></p>
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" id="GrossProfitMargin1"
                           name="selVal" value="31" class="selval">
                    <label for="GrossProfitMargin1">31%</label>

                    <input type="radio" id="GrossProfitMargin2"
                           name="selVal" value="28" class="selval">
                    <label for="GrossProfitMargin2">28%</label>

                    <input type="radio" id="GrossProfitMargin3"
                           name="selVal" value="26" class="selval">
                    <label for="GrossProfitMargin3">26%</label>

                    <input type="radio" id="GrossProfitMargin4"
                           name="selVal" value="24" class="selval">
                    <label for="GrossProfitMargin">24%</label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PayRate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.PayRate)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BurdenRate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.BurdenRate)
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Markup)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Markup)
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" id="calculate" value="Calculate" />
    <input type="submit" class="reset" value="Reset" onclick="reset()" />
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with just using a [reset button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/reset) -
 `<input type="reset" ... />`

Comment: It literally does not work, I do not know why.. but it was my first attempt and it was not resetting the fields.

Comment: It works just fine. See this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yUqUkF) - enter something in the textbox then press the 'Reset' button - the value is restored back to its original (in this case an `null` value)